# Boilerplate code for setting up Redux on a Expo/CNApp project?

Tags: react-native, create-react-app, expo

I've used [Ignite CLI](https://infinite.red/ignite) to bootstrap a simple react native project, and everything from sample components to Redux were set up and ready to go. What's missing from the Ignite project is the ability to use Expo out of the box. So I though I'd look into Expo and [Create React Native App](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app), and see if those provide a similar easy out-of-the-box Redux setup.

So does anyone know of any Expo/CNApp boilerplate code for bootstrapping a react-native project, which includes stuff like Redux and sample screens and components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expo offers a [New Project Template](https://github.com/expo/new-project-template). While it includes fonts, navigation, icons, app loading, push notifications, and some basic screens, it does not include Redux.

There are good Redux examples from [Redux.org](http://redux.js.org/).  I also found [this repo](https://github.com/jlebensold/peckish) and the [associated tutorial](https://medium.com/@jonlebensold/getting-started-with-react-native-redux-2b01408c0053) to be good a example of how to integrate Redux into a React Native app.

Comment: Great, thanks for the info. I'll check out the resources you linked to.